Drag and drop between drives no longer copies - it moves
I've noticed that when dragging a file from my laptop to my external harddrive no longer copies the file(s) - they move (with originals being deleted). Not sure what could have caused this. Luckily I only lost a few items before I noticed.
Is this happening for anyone else?
Ubuntu 24.04
Thanks.

I don't know why that's being caused, but you can use the Ctrl key while dragging the files to copy and the Shift key to move files.
Hope this helps. I'll let you know if I find a fix!!

Thanks for your reply. It just seems like such a weird problem to happen all the sudden.
